# Different bar colors for each poll choice?

Tags: polls

I know how to change ALL of the bar colors - but how do I code it so each choice bar is a different color?  I basically just need code to append the number to the "bar" class, so it would read "bar-1" , "bar-2" etc.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can help you in this regard if you not going to edit templates.

```
(function(){
   var i=0;
   jQuery('div.poll .bar .foreground').each(function(){
        i++;
        switch(i){
            case 1:
                $(this).css('background-color', '#color')
            break;
             ...
         }

    });
})();
```

Comment: I'm fine with editing the templates if that's a better way to do it.  I'm not good with jQuery at all - what would the rest (...) of that function actually look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is not simple without patchs in `poll.module` and `poll-bar.tpl.php`.

**PATCH: poll.module** Adding an additional parameter (i.e. choice id)

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme()
 */
function poll_theme() {
  return array(
    ....
    'poll_bar' => array(
      'template' => 'poll-bar',
      'arguments' => array(
          'title' => NULL, 
          'votes' => NULL, 
          'total_votes' => NULL, 
          'vote' => NULL, 
          'block' => NULL, 
          'choice_id' => null), // An additional param
    ),
  );
}
```

Changes where theme('poll_bar') is invoked. NOTE: `$i` is passed as last param

```
  foreach ($node->choice as $i => $choice) {
    if (!empty($choice['chtext'])) {
      $chvotes = isset($choice['chvotes']) ? $choice['chvotes'] : NULL;
      $poll_results .= theme('poll_bar', 
                $choice['chtext'], 
                $chvotes, 
                $total_votes, 
                isset($node->vote) && $node->vote == $i, 
                $block, 
                $i, // The additional param
                );
    }
  }
```

**PATCH: poll-bar.tpl.php** Adding classes to div.bar as `choice-x`

```
<div class="text"><?php print $title; ?></div>
<div class="bar choice-<?php print $choice_id;?>">
  <div style="width: <?php print $percentage; ?>%;" class="foreground"></div>
</div>
<div class="percent">
  <?php print $percentage; ?>% (<?php print format_plural($votes, '1 vote', '@count votes'); ?>)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying [CSS Pseudo-classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp). Specifically have a look at [:nth-of-type()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) where you can specify specific colors for each instance of a class or tag in the theme's CSS.